# Use msbuild or dotnet to render csproj without building

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild

My `Foo.csproj` uses variables. For example:

```xml
<SolutionName>MyCompany</SolutionName>
<Authors>$(SolutionName)</Authors>
```

In my build scripts I need to know the value of various properties.
I thought that would be possible using the `dotnet` or `msbuild` CLIs, so I tried:

```bash
msbuild -pp Foo.csproj
```

...but although that merges config, it doesn't render variables.

Is there some way I can get the rendered xml?

dotnet 6.0.302
msbuild 16.5.0.26101

(Maybe there's a dotnet tool for this sort of thing - but I prefer a built-in solution.)

Comment: I don't *think* there is a built-in way to do that. Also, while it seems technically possible (MSBuild does it during a real build anyway), the value it brings is questionable. For example, think about properties that change value on every build (e.g. property functions like `<P>$([System::DateTime]::UtcNow)</P>`, or a property that is also an env variable that might change, etc.). These are also issues for `-pp`, but that functionality - as I understand it - is meant to help debugging `<Import>` order and not to produce a fully equivalent project file.

Comment: @Christian.K Those are good points, thanks. If there were some way, despite those problems, I think I'd use it anyway - carefully. Would be very useful in a build environment.

Comment: Future readers: I added a [request](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/7848) for this on the msbuild repo. If you also need this functionality, please upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

The `-pp` switch outputs the result of performing all imports. Properties are not evaluated by `-pp`.

Properties are not static and their values changes over the run of a MSBuild script. If you are troubleshooting and you need to know the value of a variable at a specific point in your MSBuild script, use the `Message` task to display the value.

The `-v:d` and `-d:diag` switches can be used to get more detail in logs including the starting values of certain properties.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure that'll be of help to many readers. I need the rendered output rhough. They seem to be open to adding that as a feature, it can be tracked [here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3911).

Answer (score 0):

Currently this isn't possible, but there is a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3911) on the repo for this. They seem to be open to adding this functionality, in some form (possibly rendering a specific property, rather than the entire csproj, but even that would be useful).

Upvote that issue if you need this functionality.